# convert FAT and NTFS without data loss

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, formatting, fat32

Which one of these filesystem format conversions will keep the data on disk, and which will require backup, reformat, and restore?

1. FAT32 to NTFS
2. FAT32 to FAT16
3. NTFS to FAT32
4. NTFS to FAT16

**Note:** I want to convert my disk with Command Prompt.

Comment: as far as i known, you can't convert from NTFS to FAT32/FAT16 via convert command. FAT32 to NTFS is safe.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: Thanks. Can I convert NTFS to FAT32/16 by other programs without losing data?

Comment: Is converting NTFS to FAT32/16 an actual requirement for you? As for data loss, that's always a possibility when you perform an operation like this. It's always advisable to take a backup before attempting to convert the file system in place without reformatting.

Comment: @kikio, not sure, but i think there're reasons that `convert` does not support convert NTFS to FAT. Two basic reasons: **Max file size** and **Max volume size** of FAT are less than NTFS, see [Comparison of file systems#Limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits). and NTFS contains metadata like ACL, while FAT does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert from FAT16, FAT32 to NTFS as detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881). Doing this, like any partition operation, always carries the risk of data loss.

You CANNOT convert from NTFS back to FAT32, FAT16 without removing the partition and starting fresh.